# what is the best security postgres DB connecting unity?

Tags: postgresql, unity-game-engine

what is the best postgres DB connect unity?

Unity is known to be very vulnerable to security, so connecting a db directly with Unity was considered very unsafe, so unity -> php -> db
I am trying to make it like this. However, I found a problem with this method.

is that php security is as weak as Unity.

Do you know which method is the best way to connect postgresql to unity?

i know this question is subjective  but
I don't know where to ask these things
Or can you teach me where to ask these questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good security is not only a question of choosing certain software, it is mostly a question of design and architecture.

- Make sure you are not vulnerable to SQL injection.

  The king's way is to use prepared statements wherever possible. Also, never construct queries using string concatenation from user input.
- Make sure that the database user does not have more permissions than required. In particular, never use a superuser.
- If you are worried about eavesdroppers between the application and the database, use SSL encryption.

But security requires a holistic approach: you have to make sure that the operating system and the database are well protected and that your application is well written.